# Pre-commit results in vim

Tags: vim, pre-commit.com

In Vim 8.1, I can run `:!pre-commit run --files %` to lint and auto-format the current file. Is there some way I can turn that (or any way of calling `pre-commit`) into in-editor highlighting, like https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale does?

In the past I've run `ale` in vim with pip-installed `mypy`, `black`, and `yamllint` and brew- or apt-installed `shellcheck`, delaying shell `pre-commit` runs until after editing. The downsides to that are in addition to the delayed feedback, this only brings a subset of the hooks into my editor (`end-of-file-fixer` is missing for example) and I haven't configured all of the twice-installed hooks as `language: system`, leaving the possibility open for in-editor and out-of-editor runs to diverge on versions and arguments. I could of course switch hooks over to `language: system` but I'm hoping for a way to go with the flow of using `.pre-commit-config.yaml` as the single-source-of-truth for versions and arguments, while surfacing results in-editor.

Comment: IIRC, there is a section in ALE's documentation for writing your own "linter" (and plenty of existing ones for inspiration). If you can somehow get `pre-commit` to output information in a usable format then it should be possible to write a ALE "linter". Hell, you might even be able to write a native `:help compiler`.